# Dynamic method invoke with an instance of a class as an argument

Tags: c#, methods, invoke

I have an app that loads a given DLL, discovers its methods by reflection, and then attempts to invoke particular methods in the DLL dynamically, i.e.,
`method.Invoke ( dll, parms )`
where 'parms' is an object[] with a single member. This works fine if the parameter is a simple intrinsic type (long, double, etc.). E.g., I can load and call the various Math methods this way.

The problem occurs when I try to pass an instance of a class (which is defined in the DLL) as a parameter, e.g.,

```
namespace NS
{
    public class ABC
    {
        public long n;

        public ABC ( long i )
        {
            n = i;
        }
    }
}
```

So, `parms[0]` contains `new ABC ( 4 )`. In this case, I get the following exception:

```
Object of type 'NS.ABC' cannot be converted to type 'NS.ABC'.
```

Should this work? What is the error message actually trying to tell me? (The called method is expecting ABC as its first/only argument, which I do verify in the code at run time via `method.GetParameters()`.)

---

(much abbreviated code)

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile ( pathtoDLL );
foreach ( var type in assembly.GetTypes () ) . . .
    dynamic dll = Activator.CreateInstance ( type );
    var methods = type.GetMethods ();
```

To invoke, I look up the desired method by name in 'methods', then:

```
var parms = new object[] { new ABC ( 4 ) };
return method.Invoke ( dll, parms );
```

Comment: Show the calling code

Comment: So `instance.GetType() != typeof(ABC)`? is there something weird about how you are creating your instance? Have you somehow loaded the assembly twice?

Comment: Your code declares NS.ABC. The DLL's code also declares NS.ABC. The two types are considered different by the framework (there are a couple of ways this can happen). What you need to define NS.ABC separately and have both assemblies reference the same definition. You may find that using an `interface` rather than a class works better

Comment: @Flydog57 ABC is not declared twice, only in the DLL.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman The instance is created with new ABC ( 4 ). Have not loaded the DLL twice.

Comment: You should create an instance of ```ABC``` in that dll using reflection and then pass as an argument

Comment: @TheGeneral The calling code in question is `method.Invoke ( dll, parms )`, where 'parms' contains the single ABC object, `dll` was obtained via `dynamic dll = Activator.CreateInstance ( type )`, `method` via searching `dll.GetType().GetMethods()`

Comment: @qazwsx123 Not sure what you mean -- instantiate other than by `new ABC ( 4 )` ? The NS namespace is in the DLL, referenced via using in my app.

Comment: Here is the thing, we cant debug a story. Although this question is not so bad, it leaves a lot to be desired. I mean, if I was going to test this i have to make a whole bunch of assumptions. I think its time to provide an [mcve]

Comment: Update your question to show all that code about loading the 3rd party assembly, finding the types, creating the instances...

Comment: @TheGeneral Will do. Will take a while.

Comment: How do you create an instance of NS.ABC if that type is in in an assembly you dynamically load and whose methods you only access via reflection. When you show us your repro, this will come down to two types withe the same name, but with different type identity because of different origin or access

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Updated the question.

Comment: @Flydog57 Good point, the app knows about the DLL. The intention was to have general knowledge of the data structures and just discover the available operations on them dynamically..So, isolating ABC to a separate assembly might/should solve the problem?

Comment: To further elaborate what I'm trying to do, the app essentially implements a script interpreter, and the script can contain 'calls' to arbitrary methods. Hence, I need to be able to look up a method by name and invoke it dynamically, with no built-in pre-knowledge of what might be called.

Comment: In the mean time, thanks everyone for your incredibly quick responses.

Comment: @Flydog57 Is it possible to access and instantiate the ABC class by reflection, and so avoid what seems to be an implied conversion (which causes the exception)? I assume this is what qazwsx123 was suggesting? (That would actually make some other logic cleaner, too.)

Comment: ... never mind for now, I think I've found that answer

Answer (score 1):

Creating the argument instance by reflection, i.e., by getting a ConstructorInfo from the DLL, solves the problem. I.e., I call `dll.GetType ().GetConstructors ()`, find the one I need (by class name) and then call `constructor.Invoke ( new object[] { arg } )` to create the object.